# Runtime Error in the Max temperature Mapreduce java code

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am running a mapreduce code, an error I am getting is

```
    Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
        at test.temp$Mymapper.map(temp.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

The code is given below:

```
    package test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class temp {
    public static class Mymapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable,Text> {

        public void map(Object key, Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

            int month=Integer.parseInt(value.toString().substring(17, 19));
            IntWritable mon=new IntWritable(month);
            String temp=value.toString().substring(27,31);
            String t=null;
            for(int i=0;i<temp.length();i++){
                if(temp.charAt(i)==',')
                        break;

                else
                    t=t+temp.charAt(i);
            }

            Text data=new Text(value.toString().substring(22, 26)+t);
            context.write(mon, data);
        }


    }

    public static class Myreducer extends  Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,IntWritable> {

        public void reduce(IntWritable key,Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            String temp="";
            int max=0;
            for(Text t:values)
            {
                temp=t.toString();
                if(temp.substring(0, 4)=="TMAX"){

                    if(Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(4,temp.length()))>max){
                        max=Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(4,temp.length()));
                    }
                }
            }

            context.write(key,new IntWritable(max));
        }



        }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "temp");
        job.setJarByClass(temp.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Mymapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(Myreducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Myreducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);

        }

}
```

and the input file is

USC00300379,19000101,TMAX,-78,,,6,
USC00300379,19000101,TMAX,-133,,,6,
USC00300379,19000101,TMAX,127,,,6

kindly reply and help please!

Comment: Added an answer. Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're using TextInputFormat as input format for the job. That produces LongWritable/Text and Hadoop is deriving the map-output classes from that.

Try setting the map output classes explicitly and remove the combiner:

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
// job.setCombinerClass(Myreducer.class);
```

The combiner will only work if map and reduce output is compatible!

Comment: Ok, updated my answer. You also need to set the map output value class and unset the combiner. With those changes i got your code completes successfully!

Comment: i did that changes, its still giving the same error @oae , are you sure it ran successfully ?

Comment: Yes, i copied your code, added the 2 lines setting the key and value class and removed the combiner class! Can you carefully look if its exact the same message ? Because until i had the fix complete i received varying error messages which looked the same but looking twice i recognised they were slightly different!

Answer (score 0):

You have set the following in your driver:

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

This means, both your mapper and reducer output key class should be `IntWritable` and value class should be `IntWritable`.

The reducer is good:

```
public static class Myreducer extends  Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,IntWritable>
```

Here both the output key and value are `IntWritable`.

Problem is with the mapper:

```
public static class Mymapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable,Text>
```

Here the output key class is `IntWritable`. But, output value class is `Text` (It is expected to be `IntWritable`).

If your mapper's output key/value classes are different from your reducer's output key/value class, then you need to explicitly add following statements to your driver:

```
setMapOutputKeyClass();
setMapOutputValueClass();
```

Make following changes in your code:

- **Set map output key and value class**: In your case, since your mapper and reducer output key and value classes are different, you need to set the following:

  ```
  job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
  job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

  job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
  ```
- **Disable combiner:** Since you are using your `Reducer` code for your `Combiner`, the output of `Combiner` will be `Intwritable` and `IntWritable`. But, the `Reducer` is expecting the input as `IntWritable` and `Text`. Hence, you will get the following exception, because it got the value as `IntWritable` instead of `Text`:

  ```
  Error: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
  ```

  To remove this error, you need to disable the `Combiner`:

  ```
  job.setCombinerClass(Myreducer.class);
  ```
- **Don't use reducer as a combiner:** If you definitely need to use a combiner, then write a combiner whose output key/value are `IntWritable` and `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the below in your driver,

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

it defines the `output` classes for mapper and reducer, not just the reducer.

That means your mapper should have `connect.write(IntWritable, IntWritable)`, but you have coded `connect.write(IntWritable, Text)`.

**Fix:** When your map output  types are not same as reduce output , you need to explicitly set the output types for mapper. So, add the below in your driver code.

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the change i have made.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "temp");

        job.setJarByClass(Temp.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Mymapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Myreducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
```

Output:
10   0

For explanation follow Manjunath Ballur's post.